# IPOPT (MUMPS solver) for x64 bit windows libs required

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64, ipopt

I am trying to build a project as x64 configuration in Visual Studio 2013 which is using IPOPT- MUMPS solver binaries (Lib)

Trying to download the compatible binaries from mentioned below link:
 http://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/

Unfortunately I am  not able to find any x64 bit binary compatible with  Visual studio 2013.

How I can get the x64  IPOPT binaries of MUMPS solver for  Visual studio 2013 (Both Debug and Release mode)

If x64 bit VS2013 compatible binaries are not available then any detailed step to create the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little outdated by now, but the 3.11.0 binary release named [Ipopt-3.11.0-Win32-Win64-dll.7z](http://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.11.0-Win32-Win64-dll.7z) should work on Visual Studio 2013. You will need [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) to uncompress the archive. It contains both x86 and x64 binaries with MUMPS statically linked. In a VS 2013 project, it should suffice to include the *IpOpt-vc10.lib* and *IpOptFSS.lib* static libraries, I believe.